# Django Forms, having multiple "Models" in Meta class?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-registration

Can we define multiple models in the "Meta class" part of a Form ?

Here is my example:

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.models import User , Group

from django.forms import ModelForm

from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

from profiles.models import Student , Tutor 


class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    email           = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email Address:'))
    password        = form.CharField(label=_('Passsword:') , widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = False))
    password1       = form.CharField(label=_('Verify Passsword:') , widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = False))

    class Meta:
        model = [Student , Tutor] ## IS THIS TRUE ???
```

Comment: I never seen that. I think you should use multiple ModelFoms or single Form and use its data to make instance of each model then Model.save() for each.

Comment: @Secator : What do you mean? I'd like to write a Registration Form from scratch. I have at least two actors in system: Student and Tutors...

Comment: @Machaku : Do you mean something like "roam's" answer ?

Comment: This is not a bad question, this is a normal question. I think that this must be the good way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. But you don't need to. Instead of instantiating and validating a *single* form, do it for each type of form you need to support.

```
# Define your model forms like you normally would
class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    ...

class TutorForm(ModelForm):
    ...

class RegistrationForm(Form):
    email = ...
    ...

# Your (simplified) view:
...
context = {
    'student_form': StudentForm(),
    'tutor_form': TutorForm(),
    'registration_form': RegistrationForm()
}
return render(request, 'app/registration.html', context)

# Your template
...
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ student_form }}
    {{ tutor_form }}
    {{ registration_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

If this means field names are duplicated across forms, use [form prefixes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) to sort that out.

Comment: Many thanks for your complete answer... I have to think and fully understand it, but the points that your example made was great hints ..

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not possible to define multiple models in the Meta class.

You can create a model form for each model, and then put multiple forms in the same html `<form>` tag using the [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) argument.

Then in your view, you can check that each model forms is valid before saving.

Note that the django contrib.auth app comes with a [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) ([view source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L56)). You can probably re-use that instead of writing your own form.

Comment: I saw the source of UserCreationForm. I think I have to customize it, since I authenticate users by their email. But how can I adapt them based on These two Actors that I have (Student and Tutor) ?? I'm a bit confused ..

Comment: Subclassing `UserCreationForm` to customize the behaviour might be better than writing your own form from scratch. You don't need to adapt the form for the `Student` and `Tutor` models -- just define a separate `StudentForm` in your view and put it in the same html tag, as my and @roam's answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

## define your models in your form.py

`form1` #using 1st model

`form2` #using 2nd model

## now edit your views.py in get method

`args = {`

`"form1" = form1(),`

`"form2" = form2()`

`}`

`return render(request, "template_name", args)`

## now edit your template

`<form .....>`

`form1.as_p`

`form2.as_p`

`...`

`</form>`